# Problem with Nebular NbRoleProvider in production mode

Tags: angular, roleprovider, nebular

This is my role.provider.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

import { NbAuthService, NbAuthJWTToken } from '@nebular/auth';
import { NbRoleProvider } from '@nebular/security';

@Injectable()
export class RoleProvider implements NbRoleProvider {

  constructor(private authService: NbAuthService) {
  }

  getRole(): Observable<string> {
    return this.authService.onTokenChange()
      .pipe(
        map((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
          // console.log(token.getPayload());
          return token.isValid() ? token.getPayload()['role'] : 'guest';
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

It works fine when in development mode, but when I use production mode I get the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    getRole http://localhost:4200/main.c8da7df94aad960dcfeb.js:1
    value http://localhost:4200/main.c8da7df94aad960dcfeb.js:1
```

Comment: Please add some more related code. FYI https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What other code fragment do you need? That is the one giving me the error. I'm using ngx-admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved for me:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { NbAuthService, NbAuthJWTToken } from '@nebular/auth';

getRole(): Observable<string> {
  let result;
  this.authService.onTokenChange().subscribe((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
    if (token.isValid()) {
      result = token.getPayload()['roles'];
    } else {
      result = [];
    }
  });    
  return of(result);
}
```